# Why is there no keyword return in Dataweave

Tags: dataweave

Why is there no keyword "return" in Dataweave functions? Has it something to do with functional programming constructs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Since it is functional every expression, function and flow control structure returns a value. There is no need to add an explicit return keyword like in imperative languages.